# How do I get Greasemonkey to redirect to a local resource?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

A site that I frequent recently shut down. However, I have all the resources that I frequent backed up to my local machine. I'm attempting to access them through my bookmarks and whatnot without having to manually adjust every single bookmark. As such, I wrote a Greasemonkey Script for firefox that should redirect each file to the resource on my local drive. Here is my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Resource Redirect
// @namespace   Resource Redirect
// @include     http://www.domain.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant metadata
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var URL = window.location.href;
var newURL = URL.replace('http://www.domain.com/sites/default/files/','file:///I:/folder/files/');
// alert(newURL);
window.location.href = newURL;
```

The alert is kicking out the correct file path and name to the local resource. If I copy and paste that file path from the alert (which I'm only using for debugging purposes) into the address bar, it pulls up the correct file. So the replace and all the code up to the very last line is working. But it's not redirecting. It just stays on the existing URL and displays the 404 error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: are you getting this error in the console? `Error: Access to 'file:///I:/folder/files/...' from script denied`

Comment: No. I'm not seeing that error in the console.

Comment: try setting a "file:///" url in the console of a "http://" url - that's the error, and that's why it wont ever work - as the answer below states, this is a security policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security concerns browser restrict loading local files from script.

If you have python on your box, simplest way would be serve these files using python simple http server

```
cd I:/folder/files/

# for python 2.x :
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80

# for python 3.x :
python -m http.server 80
```

Then you can change your script to

```
var newURL = URL.replace('http://www.domain.com/sites/default/files/','http://localhost:80/');
```

Comment: I don't have python installed but you just got me thinking. I'm on a windows machine, so is it possible to use the hosts file to map something like this in the backend instead of using this script that I wrote?

Comment: Changing hosts file wouldn't help. You would need some server which can serve these files.

Comment: I took the gist of your advice. I installed easyPHP and created a localhost alias pointing to the resource folder. Modified the script to point toward that and now it works great. Thanks.